# How to access items in nested each loops in RiotJS

Tags: loops, each, riot.js

Using RiotJS, I'm trying to build a very simple editable table. I'm able to generate it like this:

```
<table-editor>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th each="{ name, key in opts.columns }">{ name }</th>
        <th>
          <button onclick="{ add }"><i class="ais ai-plus"></i></button>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr each="{ item in opts.items }">
        <td each="{ name, key in opts.columns }">
          <input type="text" onchange="{ onChange }" value="{ item[key] }">
        </td>
        <td>
          <button onclick="{ remove }">Remove</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <script>
    this.add = function (): void {
      const newItem = Object
        .keys(this.opts.columns)
        .reduce((i, key) => { i[key] = ''; return i; }, {});
      this.opts.items.push(newItem);
    };

    this.remove = function (e: RiotEvent): void {
      const { item } = e;
      const index = this.opts.items.indexOf(item);
      this.opts.items.splice(index, 1);
    };

    this.onChange = function (e: RiotEvent): void {
      const { item } = e;
      console.error(item, ' is column, not item... ');
      const index = this.opts.items.indexOf(item);
      // TODO: Update the item
    };
  </script>
</table-editor>
```

The problem is that `e.item` which comes with the `onChange` event is the column object, and not the item object. It's because of the nested each loop, but how do I get around this? There's of course no `parent` on the item to go "up", using `parent.onChange` also obviously makes no difference...

**How do I get the item so I can change it in the array?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, in this particular case, I could work around it by simply moving the onchange event up to the table row, like this:

```
<tr each="{ item in opts.items }" onchange="{ onChange }">
  <td each="{ name, key in opts.columns }">
   <input type="text" name="{ key }" value="{ item[key] }">
  </td>
  <td>
    <button onclick="{ remove }">Remove</button>
  </td>
</tr>
```

However, a side-effect of this, for some reason I don't understand, is that I `e.item` is now `e.item.item`... meaning my (finished) `onChange` event becomes this:

```
this.onChange = function (e: RiotEvent): void {
  const { item: { item }, target: { name, value } } = e;
  const index = this.opts.items.indexOf(item);

  tag.opts.items[index][name] = value;
};
```